# Magento 2 calculate custom text fields length and width on product view page

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, jquery, json

How is possible in magento 2.0?
I successfully active in magento 1.9 for bellow thing.
I am trying to create a product with two custom text fields: Length and Width. When the user types, both a length and width, the price needs to calculate via custom formula.

I'm trying to find the correct event to connect an observer. Anybody know what that might be?

Here's what I know and have tried:

1. The custom field text box in the product view has an `onChange` event
   that I haven't figured out how to tap into yet via an observer event
   `opConfig.reloadPrice()`
2. If I build an observer on the event `sales_quote_add_item`, then I can 
   change the price via formula when it's added to the cart. With this
   method I still need a way to change it in the product view before
   it's added to cart.
3. I've also tried the event `catalog_product_get_final_price` but this
   seem to only fire when the product page is loaded, so after a
   product length or width is added, it doesn't re-fire.

   Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!